# Mysql - Views are automatically converted into empty tables with default datatype tinyint(4)

Tags: mysql, database, view, google-cloud-platform

In google cloud hosted platform, for my project i created some mysql views. approximately those views are having 10k rows.

After some time views are automatically converted into empty tables with table name as respective view name. Columns in that table are set to default datatype tinyint(4).

At the time of views to table conversion, views are deleted automatically and created table has empty rows.

**If i execute an select statement with view_name it fetches data from created table not from view( because there is no view in that name ). so it gives empty data.**

If i delete those empty tables and recreate that views then i can able to get those data's on select query.

After sometime, again views are automatically converted into tables. Then it select query returns empty data.

This process happens regularly.

**Why views are automatically converted into empty tables?**

[Snapshot of a converted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkODz.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Do you have a question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the question. Pls check it out above

Comment: MySQL does not have such functionality, so I would ask google support, if you are sure that it is not your code that does it.

Comment: This issue happens periodically in all my servers( prod, test and live ) that has identical configuration. One of the query i used to create a view. CREATE VIEW all_opportunity_view AS  SELECT a.customer_id,a.callback_id, a.login_id,b.visited_flag FROM product a INNER JOIN product_dtl b ON a.product_id=b.product_id 
WHERE  a.flag IN (1,3,4,6)  GROUP BY  a.product_id ;

Comment: Views are working fine for me with version 5.7.11-google

Comment: Thanks for your attention. My Mysql version is 5.5.50-0+deb8u1. I 'm checking all my db's regularly from past few days. Until now this issue is not yet happened. If it happens again, i will get some detailed information at that issue.